# How to remove the the lower and upper 1% data points outliers from a dataset using R?

Tags: r

I　have a dataset containing noise points. How can I remove the lower and upper 1% data points using R ?

1,200,211,259,177,188, 1000, 2,188,203,200,198

1, 2 and 100 are outliers

Comment: In which way didn't any of [**these posts**](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+remove+outliers) help you?

Comment: You could remove the values outside the boundaries of `quantile(x, c(0.01, 0.99))`

Answer (score 0):

method 1: Pauta criterion or 3σ criterion

```
data<-c(1,200,211,259,177,188, 1000, 2,188,203,200,198)
while(1){ 
  s_data<-(data-mean(data))/sd(data) #standardized
  m<-mean(s_data)
  s<- sd(s_data)
  if (length(data)==length(data[(s_data<m+3*s)&(s_data>m-3*s)])){
    break; #if data do not change and loop will stop
  }else{
    data<-data[(s_data<m+3*s)&(s_data>m-3*s)]
  }
}
data

## [1]   1 200 211 259 177 188   2 188 203 200 198
```

as you can see ,this method could not rejecting the abnormal value 1 and 2 .
so,here is the method 2:use grubbs method

```
library(outliers)
grubbs.test(data,type=11)
```

and this is method 3: 
use the kmeans cluster method (divided data into three parts,the first part is the lowest part,the second part is the highest value,the third part is the normal value)

```
kmeans(data,3)
#Clustering vector:
# [1] 2 3 3 3 3 3 1 2 3 3 3 3
```